# Why grep on remote system says file or directory not available

Tags: ssh, grep, wildcards

I'm trying to run a grep command on remote system to give me the result for May 22. But reply comes

**/bin/grep: /var/log/Clients_Logs/127.0.0.1/*: No such file or directory**

But when I specifically provide the filename, it works and gives me the results.

This command gives me an error

```
ssh -tt emerg@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  'sudo /bin/grep -r "May 22" /var/log/Clients_Logs/127.0.0.1/*'
```

Comment: **Problem** : * is not getting expanded and there really is no such file named * ; **Solution** : try removing the last * and it will work.

Comment: Yes @Prem you are right , it did work thanks. Please put it answer section so i can commit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem** : * is not getting expanded ; there really is no such file named * , so grep reports that.

**Solution** : remove the last * ; it will work with -r , making grep look into all the files in that Directory.

Comment: And the cause, I'm guessing, is that the directory is only accessible by root, therefore the shell doesn't have enough permissions to expand `*` there (since this happens before sudo).

Comment: Correct , @grawity ; At the very least , that Directory may not be accessible by user "emerg" , who is executing the sudo.